# Absolute and relative positioning involving media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

So I'm trying to recreate the following layout for a lab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LBFR.jpg

I've started by tackling the navigation bar. I set the position to absolute so I can give it a top: 50px; property to move it down 50px from the top.

I tried to then set the logo's position to relative, so that relative to the navigation bar, I can move it 20px from the left or so. But when I use relative positioning, the logo sits inside of the navigation bar and makes the navigation bar's height bigger.

I thought that by setting the logo's position to relative, it would treat the logo as if it's not a part of the navigation bar. However, that's not the case. So what I did was I also set the logo's position to absolute. This entire thing is just killing my soul. For some reason I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

I went to web archive, and looked up spigot design's website. What they did, was they set the navigation bar's position to fixed, and the logo to relative. I tried doing this as well but the logo would still sit inside the navigation bar and extend it's height.

Furthermore, I have to set the logo to sit in the middle of the navigation bar when the browser is 768px and below. And then, two menu links sit to the left of the logo, and the other two menu links sit to the right of the logo. I'm completely lost at how to do this. I don't think I'd have a problem with the rest of the layout. It's just this navigation bar and logo positioning that's driving me insane.

Here is my code: http://cryptb.in/v48Y#cf572c29a798b3c6593631d831c8a323

Should I upload my code with the logo images as well? That may make it easier to follow. I'm not sure what the best practice is as I'm new to stack overflow.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lab Eight</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- navigation bar left -->
  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="float-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="column-twelve">

      </div>

      <div class="column-twelve">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);
body {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
/* Horizontal line to divide content */
hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #332929;
}
#logo {
  background: url('images/logo-left.png');
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: -20px;
}
.column-twelve h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
.column-twelve h2 {
  font-size: 1.875em;
}
.row .column-twelve p {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.875em;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
/* Acts as a container to wrap all the content so it doesn't take up 100% of the page. */
.container {
  width: 90%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 58px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #fefefe;
}
.navbar li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar li a {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* The row for the columns. */
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.column-twelve {
  width: 100%;
}
.column-eleven {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.column-ten {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.column-nine {
  width: 75%;
}
.column-eight {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.column-seven {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.column-six {
  width: 50%;
}
.column-five {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.column-four {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.column-three {
  width: 25%;
}
.column-two {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.column-one {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('images/logo-center.png');
    height: 146px;
    width: 250px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add your code.

Comment: Ok, I added my code as part of my comment.

Comment: add your code js fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g8h58ye3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/avrXaE?editors=110

To complete this, I positioned the `#navbar` relative to its normal position. Then I absolutely positioned the `#logo` and `#container` (from their first positioned ancestor element, i.e. `#navbar`.)

The height issue comes from setting `min-height: 58px;` on `.navbar`. Instead, you want to use `height: 58px;`.

FYI--when using media queries, it is best practice to write your code ***mobile first***. This means writing your code for the smallest screen first. In order to do this, you must use `min-width` instead of `max-width`. Also, you want to use `@media only screen`, instead of `@media screen`. This targets only browsers that can understand media queries.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask any questions about the code in the comments section.

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <ul id="container">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

body {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#page {
  height: 600px;
}

#navbar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 75px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

#logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar li {
  display: none;
}

#navbar li a {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar li:nth-child(3) a, 
#navbar li:nth-child(4) a {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 569px) {
  #navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  #logo {
    left: 50px;
    transform: translate(0);
  }

  #container {
    width: 30%;
    right: 50px;
  }

  #navbar li {
    width: 25%;
  }

  #navbar li:nth-child(3) a, 
  #navbar li:nth-child(4) a {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:
In response to your additional questions:

1. `:nth-child()` is a pseudo-class selector. It selects the child that is the desired ordinal (i.e. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc.) of its parent. The ordinal is designated by the number in parentheses. So if you look at my code, you'll see `li:nth-child(3)`. This means: select all **`li`** elements that are the **3rd child** of their parent. If the 3rd child isn't an `li` element, it will **NOT** be selected.
2. In regards to your media query question: The reason I placed the `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%);` code outside of the media query, is because I'm using the ***mobile first*** method of coding. ***Mobile First*** design is the current standard for responsive design. It means that you are designing for the smallest screen (mobile) first. So, I am centering the logo, and removing the text links, outside of the media query. Then I target the tablet in my first media query: `@media only screen and (min-width: 569px)`. This targets screens that have a resolution of 569px or higher, and adds the text links in the nav bar. Finally, I use another media query: `@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)` to target larger screens (computers), with a screen size of 769px or higher. In this media query, I position the logo on the left and the text links on the right.

**NOTE**: In your code, you are using ***desktop first*** design. You are designing for the large screen first. Then you use media queries for smaller sizes. That's why **your** media query uses `max-width`. I'm using ***mobile first*** design. I am designing for the small screen first. Then I use media queries for larger sizes. That's why **my** media query uses `min-width`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't learned what "nth-child" does yet but that's something I can probably look up on my own. Unless of course you feel like you have a good explanation.  
One thing I noticed is, you set the left property for the logo to 50% outside of the media query. How does this work? Because the way I view it is you want the logo to move left 50% (middle) once the resolution goes down.  
Once again, thank you. Your code looks really clean. This is something I'm striving to do as I'm learning. I feel like I often over complicate how to do something.

Comment: Please see the edit in my answer. Also, please upvote my answer if you feel it is useful. Thanks! And as for your code--you will find ways to simplify and clean up your code as you continue learning. Any other questions, let me know.